# IMAP4_SSL error retrieving gmail using Python with an Arduino Yún

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, imaplib, arduino-yun

The hell began when when we tried to go to Arduino Yún's linino environment.

Initially we used this code:

```
import imaplib
import email
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('user@example.com', 'password')
mail.list()
```

And eventually we got:

> arduino object has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'

After some research we tried importing del ssl library:

```
import imaplib
import email
import ssl
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('user@example.com', 'password')
mail.list()
```

But in this occasion we got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail-processor.py", line 3, in <module>
  import ssl
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
  import _ssl # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

Well, any idea about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] My friend and colleague @marcelofpalves have find out the solution: **Installing the python-openssl library**. Now all works like a charm. Thanks Marcelo.

From bash:

```
opkg update
opkg install distribute
opkg install python-openssl
```

For more information visit: *http://playground.arduino.cc/Hardware/Yun#installing_python_module*